# How to reverse arp using nping for Windows

Tags: networking, mac, ip, nmap, arp

I would like to send a reverse ARP to resolve an IP address given a MAC address using [nping for Windows](http://nmap.org/nping/).

The documentation is not clear on how this should work and I'm unable to find any examples online.

Here is what I have tried:

```
C:\>nping --arp --arp-type rarp-request --arp-target-mac 00-AA-BB-CC-DD-EE
WARNING: No targets were specified, so 0 hosts pinged.

C:\>nping --arp --arp-type rarp-request --arp-target-mac 00-AA-BB-CC-DD-EE 10.10.10.10
Starting Nping 0.6.47
SENT (0.1560s) RARP who is 00:AA:BB:CC:DD:EE? Tell 00:AA:BB:CC:DD:EE
SENT (1.1560s) RARP who is 00:AA:BB:CC:DD:EE? Tell 00:AA:BB:CC:DD:EE
SENT (2.1560s) RARP who is 00:AA:BB:CC:DD:EE? Tell 00:AA:BB:CC:DD:EE
SENT (3.1560s) RARP who is 00:AA:BB:CC:DD:EE? Tell 00:AA:BB:CC:DD:EE

Max rtt: N/A | Min rtt: N/a | Avg rtt: N/A
Raw packets sent: 5 (210B) | Rcvd: 0 (0B) | Lost: 5 (100.00%)
```

Comment: Please do not [double post](http://serverfault.com/q/667567/167012).  Rather pick the site that you feel will give you the best answer and post there.

Answer (score 1):

cf Server Fault:
Sorry for not answering your question with using nping only. The protocol RARP is obsolete so I believe you will not get a rarp reply to your rarp-request.
I believe you can achieve what you looking for by typing :

> nping --rate=5 ***172.16.5.0-255*** & arp -a | findstr
>   "***ec-f4-bb-6a-91-9c***"

The first command ping all host in **your subnet** to update your ARP table, the second perfom print the table and filter **the mac** you're looking for.

Please note that you can not reverse lookup an host that belong to a different subnet.

Answer (score 0):

Since DHCP is used nowadays over the (obsolete) RARP protocol, you might find this query useful. Unlike the previous one, you do not need to update your ARP table so the command is much faster :

```
netsh dhcp server \\<DHCP_Server> scope <Network_Address> show clients 1 | findstr <MAC>
```

Comment: Does that require domain admin privileges or does it have to be run from the dhcp server machine? I don't have Win server 2008 handy and the technet docs didn't seem too clear on this. What does it actually do?